# how to switch between 2 connections on windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, modem, netsh

Is there a way (I guess there is) to switch between 2 internet connections on my windows 7/8/10 ?

I have my wifi connected AND my USB android modem and I would like to switch programatically (command line) from one to other.

Mybe some netsh command ?

[image]

I want to switch between proxymis.com network and androidS4 on my wifi.

Comment: This allows to switch between LAN and WLAN. But I want to switch between 2 different wifi connections I have on WLAN: I added a picture

Comment: It's the same solution. Just replace "Local Area Connection" and "Wireless Network Connection" with the names of your two wireless connections. Disable one and enable the other.

Comment: I tried this:  netsh interface set interface name="AndroidS4" admin=enabled
It says: "interface with this name is not registered on router"
Same error with proxymis.com

Comment: You need `netsh interface set interface "proxymis.com 3" Disable` followed by `netsh interface set interface "Resaue 4" Enable` **or** `netsh interface set interface "proxymis.com" Disable` followed by `netsh interface set interface "AndroidS4" Enable`. I'm not sure which names you need to use. You don't need `name=` for sure.

Comment: Found the solution: "netsh wlan connect name=proxymis.com"
Regards